# Proof that $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac{x^{4}y}{(x^{2}+y^{2})^2} = 0$ using homogeneity of the function

Tags: limits, analysis, multivariable-calculus

At first I tried to prove this by trying to construct and epsilon-delta proof but to no avail. Instead I've tried to use homogeneity to prove this.

Consider $\frac{x^{4}y}{(x^{2}+y^{2})^2} = f(x, y)$. We see that

$f(\lambda x, \lambda y) = \frac{\lambda^{4}x^{4}y\lambda}{(\lambda^{2}x^{2}+\lambda^{2}y^{2})^2} = 
\frac{\lambda^{4}x^{4}y\lambda}{\lambda^{4}(x^{2}+y^{2})^2} = \frac{\lambda^{4}x^{4}y\lambda}{(\lambda^{2}(x^{2}+y^{2}))^2} =
\lambda\frac{x^{4}y}{(x^{2}+y^{2})^2} = \lambda f(x, y)$

So $f(x, y)$ is homogeneous of degree $\alpha = 1$. Because $f(0, 0)$ is undefined, $f(x, y)$ is continuous and homogeneous with degree $\alpha = 1 > 0$ it follows that $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac{x^{4}y}{(x^{2}+y^{2})^2} = 0$.

Is this proof correct? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, correct (but I don't see how "$f(0,0)$ undefined" is useful). Or simply: $|f(x,y)|\le|y|.$

Comment: you can also solve it using polar coordinates or alternatively noting that $\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}\le x^{-2}$

Comment: @AnneBauval Thanks! It could be I wrote it incorrectly, the syllabus that I was provided says that the function should not exist in the origin, or is this generally not important?

Comment: ("$\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}\le x^{-2}$", i.e. $x^2\le x^2+y^2$, was my "Or simply $|f(x,y)|\le|y|$"). The existence of $f(0,0)$ is not important here.

Comment: The proof is that $f$ is bounded on the circle $S^1=\{(x,y):x^2+y^2=1\}$ since $S^1$ is compact, say with minimum $m$ and maximum $M$. But then $m\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\le f(x,y)\le M\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ for all $x$ and $y$, so the limit as $(x,y)\to(0,0)$ is $0$.